# Guitar Hero Live controller issue on pc

Tags: pc, controllers, guitar-hero-live, frets-on-fire

I recently bought a Guitar Hero Live guitar controller included with the PS3 game. I also have Frets on Fire installed on my PC, so I thought I was able to play with that guitar with no problems.

But there is a problem (of course) and it's pretty huge: I cannot strum and press a note at the same time. I know it's not a hardware-related problem, because my PC recognizes the input from every button/strum bar, but not if done at the same time.

Is there a workaround, some drivers to install or is it impossible to use the Guitar Hero Live guitar for PS3 on PC?

Comment: Do you have any other guitars from a different version of guitar hero to try (or perhaps a friend has one you can borrow)?  If it works for a different guitar, you'll at least know its just that particular guitar.  Besides trying that, I'm doubting a driver that fixes this is out there.

Comment: Nope, I just have this guitar only

Comment: They really changed the way the guitar works for GH Live, so it is quite possible that this won't work very well, even if it does work, as I believe FoF is using the 5x1 button scheme as opposed to the new 3x2 GH Live button scheme.

Comment: I know that, but it's more of a problem related to Windows and not FoF. If i go on control panel and check the buttons, the strum bar is associated to X and Y Axis while the buttons to some numbers. Buttons light up when i press them, axis move when i strum, but axis doesn't move when i strum while pressing one or more button

Comment: are you using any software to get windows to recognize the controller? Or did it "just work" when you plugged it in?

Comment: Windows recognized it without any additional software. Plugged it in with the ps3 bluetooth dongle

Comment: @MattiaNocerino What does the device show up as in 'Devices and Printers' or 'Device Manager'? (Basically what does Windows think the controller is).

Comment: It showed up as Guitar Hero Controller if i remember correctly

Comment: @MattiaNocerino How are you sure it's not a hardware problem?  The hardware could have some problem with sending the two signals at the same time, but not individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this is a very old thread now but I have a solution that worked for me.
The issue has to do with the way the standard drivers for the dongle do not support multiple simultaneous button presses. This is specific to PSx dongles and the issue is not present if you pair your controller to an XBOX360 GHL dongle.

There is a relatively new project called GHLPokeMachine to provide support for PS3 and PS4 Guitar Hero Live controllers which should work for your PS3 controller. You run the small executable and it detects the inputs from the guitar controller and passes them correctly, including multi-button presses. You then start up Frets on Fire or Clone Hero and redo your keybinds.  It's very easy to use.

It worked perfectly for me and my GH Live PS4 dongle.

All credit to the developers.
Here is the [current version](https://github.com/Octave13/GHLPokeMachine/releases/tag/master1.1) but if it ever disappears just search for GHLPokeMachine.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, if you have Win10, it will be recognized immediately and it will work without any problem ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/GuitarHero/comments/41dmg3/can_i_use_guitar_hero_live_guitar_on_pc/cz1ps17/)). So I'll assume you don't have Win10.

Most players out there use a software called Xpadder to map keys on the Guitar Hero Live (GHL) controller, so it can be used on a PC.
[This Reddit subject](https://www.reddit.com/r/GuitarHero/comments/41dmg3/can_i_use_guitar_hero_live_guitar_on_pc/cz1ldq0/) shows that all controllers should work on:

> The Guitar Hero Live guitar controller will work on the following platforms: PlayStation 3, PlayStation 4, Wii U , Xbox 360, Xbox One, and iOS.

The player having an issue had the game on xbox360, but as it is stated the controller is the same for all platforms.

About Xpadder: the first answer of [this reddit subject](https://www.reddit.com/r/GuitarHero/comments/356jpe/need_help_with_ps3_guitar_controller_on_pc/cr1fwyn/) explains how to use a GH controller on a PC using Xpadder. The user even did [a video tutorial.](https://youtu.be/nw0uqM7YaCw) As I can't trust a file posted on a google drive, [here is another tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/playstation-guitar-hero-controller-pc-mac/) explaining how to do it (PC and MAC).

So, to sum up: **Yes, a GHL controller for PS3 can be used on PC**, but:

- you can use directly your GHL controller if you have Win10
- if you don't, using Xpadder will likely solve the problem, as you can map the commands using this software.

Comment: I have already tried to use xpadder and it didn't work. However, i feel guilty not accepting your answer, as probably i've done something wrong while trying to configure the software. I'll try someday in the future (the guitar it's not mine) and i'll let you know. I the meantime, +1!

Comment: Would it be possible to run WiiU version on PC (with wiiu dongle)?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I have not tested it yet, but it's because of the USB dongle... Many people on the web are saying that it must be a xbox360 dongle, which is compatible with all GHL controllers. The other USB dongles don't seem to use the same way to understand the guitar's entries and send them to your computer... Anyway you can test that on http://html5gamepad.com .

Sorry if you don't understand very well, I'm not english...

Hope it helped